# How to store dynamic delimited fields from configuration file in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-data, delimiter

I have a configuration file where some fields are mentioned in the following way:

```
;
Student Name; Enroll. No.; Std; Age
```

where first line tell about delimiter and second line shows fields delimited by the above delimiter. Fields are dynamic as it is a configuration file.

Delimiter could be ,/;/:
Fields are not in fix number.
Field names will change with scenario.
Input file data to be formated according to field

I have to understand this configuration file using C code. Please guide me in this

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "dynamic"? Do you mean the number of fields and their meaning could change? Does that mean the second line is actually a list of field names and then 3rd line and beyond are actually data corresponding to those fields?

Comment: Yes, the number of fields and fields' name will change as one can configure them. There is another file with input data, delimited with same delimiter. we also need to detect irregularity in input data but that we can do later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll describe an approach algorithmically, with some C hints. You can make an attempt to implement this in detail in C:

1. Read the first line of the configuration file into a string buffer and store the first character into a `delimiter` variable (Note: this assumes of course that the first character of this line is what you want).
2. Read the second line of the configuration file into a string buffer and, using `strtok` and the `delimiter` saved in step 1 as the string delimiter, read each of the column names from that line, copying them into an array of column names (Note: you can have an array of `char *` with fixed maximum number of elements, and allocate each string memory dynamically as you go, copying the strings from pointers given by `strtok`). In this step, record how many columns you recorded, `num_columns`.
3. Open and read the data file line by line. You can use `strtok` here and operate on each string item using whatever method needed. Since your configuration file doesn't indicate data types, you'll need to assume that they're all strings, unless you want to make assumptions based upon certain column names.

That's a basic approach. You can fill in the blanks on error checking and general housekeeping (closing files where appropriate, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the algo, the last token is containing \n as part of string. How can I eliminate it from buffer?

Comment: @user1517650 You can pass in a string of separators, so pass your `delimiter` concatenated with `'\n'` as a two-character string as the set of separators for `strtok` to use.

Comment: What is the scope of a buffered string? I have a global double pointer to hold the fields as they encountered in loop in a function. After returning from function, the last element of fields i.e fields[3] become out of bound just after a file opened. While if I use malloc rather than referencing to a buffer, it works fine. So does that mean, scope of a buffered string or string literal is just within a scope it's defined?

Comment: @user1517650 one thing to keep in mind is that `strtok` modifies the original string to perform its function. See `man strtok` notes on this. If you have some code now and still having some issues, please feel free to add it to your question for further comment.